# Trying to alternate power supplies seamlessly when a certain current threshold is hit?

Tags: power-supply, current-measurement, lithium-ion, switching

*I don't know much about electronics so asking the right questions is troublesome sorry about that.*

I need to swap from a 1S Li-Ion battery with cylindrical cells 3.8v to a 1S Li-ion battery with pouch cells also 3.8v. I need to do so seamlessly as to not restart the controller it's powering. The problem is that I need it to switch based on what current load the controller is pulling. Preferably at 10-15amp it would switch inputs from the cylindrical Li-Ion to the pouch Li-ion battery because the cylindrical Li-Ion just can't handle much more current however the pouch Li-ion battery can.
What would the mysterious item be that could swap these inputs depending on amp draw, like a fuse but instead popping it switches?

Many thanks :)

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem to be honest. Why not just run off the LiPo all the time? The circuit you're asking for is not just one component and by the time you're done the effort will not have been worth it. Tracking regulators, bi-directional switches and other junk.

Comment: Can you describe what you want to do without using nonsense words such as "seamlessly"? We are not making undergarments here.

Comment: and (assuming the two batteries are similar enough) why not parallel them and have the capacity of both, all the time?

Comment: lipos are too heavy at higher C rating and capacity. To utilize both battery types and optimize for their pros while ''negating'' the cons. Lipo gives the power Liion gives the endurance. liion can't give both reliably and lipo gets too heavy... Try find a >60C+ 1S 3000mah Lipo battery that isn't over 150grams. Liion is 48grams and 3000mah w/connector, while the 750mah lipo is 34grams w/connector. There's a lot more too it. 

To the coconut who mocked the word ''seamlessly'' if the voltage were to drop for a second the controller would restart and cause havoc seamlessly is the correct word.

Comment: A generic UPS for basic home use will switch over in about 10 ms using inexpensive circuitry, In that context 1 second is an incredibly long time. I think @Elliot is asking for more specificity, when you say "if the voltage were to drop for a second..." - how much time is this specifically? (e.g. 1000ms? 10ms? 10us?)